# Use 2 databases in the same query in Grails

Tags: grails, datasource

In my grails application I have an sql query that selects column data from 1 database based on a column in another database.
Thus it is interacting with 2 databases in the SAME query.

Is there a way to pick data from 1 database based on data retrived from another database.
In a scenario like this, how would you put down the code.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way through.

Created 2 domain objects, Cdisc and Tape. 
cdisc and tape are 2 tables in 2 different databases. Both the tables have a common primary Id, player_id.
The idea is to display data from these 2 tables on one page.

Cdisc.groovy

```
package tune  

class Cdisc {  
String name  
double cId  
String id  

static mapping = {
    table 'cdisc'  
    version false       

    columns {  
        id column:'player_id'   
        cId column:'c_id'  
        name column: 'name'  
    }  
}  
}
```

Tape.groovy

```
package tune

class tape {

    String id   
String tapeDate
String comments 


static mapping = {
    table 'tape'
    version false       
    columns {       
        id column:'player_id'       
         tapeDate column:'tape_date'
         comments column: 'comments'
}

}



public def getName(){       
    def cdisc = Cdisc.findById(this.id)     
    return cdisc.name
}

}
```

TapeController.groovy

```
def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)

    [tapeInstanceList: tape.findAllByCommentsLike('%Test%'),     tapeInstanceTotal: Tape.count()]

}
```

Finally displaying name from table cdisc using the getter

list.gsp

```
    <g:each in="${tapeInstanceList}" status="i"
        var="tapeInstance">
        <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">

            <td><g:link action="edit" id="${tapeInstance.id}">
                ${fieldValue(bean: tapeInstance, field: "id")}
            </g:link></td>

            <td>
            ${fieldValue(bean: tapeInstance, field: "tapeDate")}
            </td>

            <td>
            ${fieldValue(bean: tapeInstance, field: "comments")}
            </td>

             <td>${tapeInstance.getName()}</td>


    </g:each>
```

Thus we are using a getter to get the data from the 2nd table in another database.
Worked for me. Let me know if theres any other workaround.